# Android Support Library errors

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have recently updated a project that makes use of the Android Support Library ( android-support-v4.jar )

I updated the support library by "Android Tools > Add Support Library"

After doing this my project fails to build and the following imports that worked fine previously now error.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat.OnQueryTextListenerCompat;
```

With errors long the lines of "The import android.support.v4.widget cannot be resolved"

What have I done wrong? how do I get it working again?

Comment: Make sure `android-support-v4.jar` is in your `libs/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which API are you using? It is best to use the Android SDK Manager in Eclipse(ADT) plugin to download the support libraries.

The Android Support v4 JAR needs to be in the 'libs' folder of your project. Make sure you have the JAR 'copied' in the folder. It is best to manually do it yourself to make sure it is there.

The best way to fix the 'red' import errors in Eclipse is

```
Ctrl + Shift + O
```

to automatically import the correct imports.

Please let me know if this helps! I have had problems with Android imports as well.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The jar file also needs to be in your build path.

Comment: As I said, the JAR needs to be in the 'libs' folder. :)

Comment: @JaredBurrows it can be in the `libs` folder without being in the build path, e.g. by copying an external jar to the folder. Then you'd need to right-click the jar `Build path > Add to Build Path`

Comment: I clearly say this in my answer "The Android Support v4 JAR needs to be in the 'libs' folder of your project. Make sure you have the JAR 'copied' in the folder. It is best to manually do it yourself to make sure it is there.".